# Scraping Dynamic Javascript Site with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, curl, web-scraping

I've run into this issue a few times, and found quite a few similar requests on here, but none which give a straightforward solution that I'm able to use (bear with me, I'm no much of a programmer!)...

In the past I've built quite a few php scripts to scrape pages using curl, and conceptually it's very simple - all the html of the page being scraped gets pulled in and I can search for whatever is relevant. Simple, even I can do that! ;-)

But I'm coming across more and more sites which dynamically load in their content, meaning curl does not return the final html which is displayed.  In a nutshell, what I'd like is to be able to work just how I was,  with the final HTML available through curl, but it does not seem to work like that.

I don't know if I'm being clear, so here are a couple of examples using budget airline sites... the problem is a little different in each case but in both instances I just want the final content! (Had to trim http://www.easyjet.com/ off the front of all URLs as it won't let me post more than 2 links):

Deep-linking into easyjet.com will have one of two results... if flights are on sale, such as this example, then it will originally redirect to /en/buy/flights, and then immediately to /en/buy/seats:

/deeplink?dep=LPL&dest=ACE&dd=2018-09-01&xdfn=7157&apax=1

If they are not on sale, it will stop on /en/buy/flights:

/deeplink?dep=LPL&dest=ACE&dd=2020-09-01&xdfn=7157&apax=1

However, curl cannot follow the redirect.  The following script will return /en/buy/flights as the Redirected URL:

```
<? 

 $url="http://www.easyjet.com/deeplink?dep=LPL&dest=ACE&dd=2018-09-01&xdfn=7157&apax=1";   

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);           

  $html = curl_exec($ch);

  $redirectedUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

  curl_close($ch);

  echo "Original URL:   " . $url . "<BR>";
  echo "Redirected URL: " . $redirectedUrl . "\n<BR><BR>";
?>
```

My other example is more straightforward to explain...

https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/ does not initially load any content other than a "loading" type icon of a plane going round in a circle.  Turn off javascript, and that is all you'll ever see in your browser!

Any attempt to use curl to scrape the page just results in my script hanging indefinitely...

```
 <?

     $url="https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/";              

      $ch = curl_init();

      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);           

      $html = curl_exec($ch);

      curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```

I'm hoping to avoid having to pick apart all the javascript, and just find a way to get straight to the content as loaded on a browser.  I'm also hoping to to do so without having to install and learn how to use too many different technologies... apart form anything else my pretty cheap hosting provider keep the server pretty locked down and are pretty unhelpful when it comes to installing any non-standard packages, extensions etc!

Fingers crossed...

Comment: You'll have to actually run the Javascript, there's no way around it. So curl is out of the question, you'll need a (headless) browser that runs the site, decide how long to wait and then read the DOM. There's no "the page is now done" event, that's the very nature of a dynamic website.

Comment: Thanks Ingo.  So I've seen similar replies, and PhantomJS seems to come up as probably the most popular option.  Am I correct in understanding that PhantomJS itself is a standalone package which would need installing on the server, and then I'd need to use the PHP PhantomJS library to control it from within PHP?

Comment: One other question... if I was using python instead of PHP would it make the situation any more straightforward?